# Adding a child form to a Non MDI win form prevents child controls inside child form mouse clickable

Tags: c#, winforms

I am adding a child form inside a parent form without setting MDI parent of child form to parent form. Following is the code :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChildForm openForm = new ChildForm();
    openForm.Show();
    openForm.Visible = true;
    openForm.TopLevel = false;
    this.Controls.Add(openForm);
}
```

Clicking text inside any control within child form just selects the text completely and does not allow editing text directly using mouse. Editing text using keyboards is working fine though.

[image]

I cannot set ChildForm.MDI= this because of some other issues with a tab control. Is there any way to prevent this and allow user to edit text using mouse.

Comment: Windows is getting pretty confuzzled by the style flags for the window.  You can tell for example by it using the completely wrong visual style.  You really *do* need to add             openForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;  Google "dockpanel suite" to get ahead with this.

Comment: Setting FormBorderStyle.None does solve the problem. Thanks a lot for pointing that out. This setting distorts the child screens completely. Is there any other quick fix like this to solve this problem as well?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in metroframework

```
private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.TopLevel = true;
    frm.Opacity = 10;
    frm.Show();
    frm.ControlBox = false;
    frm.Movable = false;
    frm.BorderStyle = MetroFormBorderStyle.None;
    frm.DisplayHeader = false;
    frm.TopLevel = false;
    panel1.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    frm.BringToFront();
    this.TopMost = true;
    frm.StyleManager = metroStyleManager1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `UserControl` instead. It is designed the same way as a `Form` but it does not have borders and it is intended to be used inside other forms.

You only have to compile the project that contains it once so that it appears in Visual Studio toolbox (assuming the project is in the same solution and is either the same project as the one containing the `Form` or has a reference to it.

Or alternatively, you can load it dynamically similar to what you have done in your example. But if you systematically load the same single user control, it is easier to do in the designer...

Sometime, you might also want to make some adjustment to the layout.