# Textbox controls created in child form is not selectable by mouse

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the below situation in my project.

Class 'UserForm' is derived from Windows.Form class, it has a TextBox control on it. An instance of the class 'UserForm' (userForm1) is created and is shown. Another instance of 'UserForm' (userForm2) is created and its parent is set as userForm1 and shown.

I can select the text in the textbox control in userForm1 using mouse. But TextBox control on userForm2 doesn't allow selection of text using mouse or cursor cannot be set using mouse. Only double clicking on the control selects the text. Note that I can select text using keyboard though.

```
//MainForm.cs
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            this.Load += new EventHandler(MainForm_Load);
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;

            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(900, 600);
        }

        public void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            UserForm userForm1 = new UserForm();
            userForm1.Text = "User Form 1";
            userForm1.MdiParent = this;
            userForm1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(820, 465);
            userForm1.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Normal;
            userForm1.Show();

            UserForm userForm2 = new UserForm();
            userForm2.TopLevel = false;
            userForm2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 100);
            userForm2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(820, 465);
            userForm2.Text = "User Form 2";
            userForm2.Show();
            userForm2.Parent = userForm1;
        }
    }
}

//UserForm.cs
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class UserForm : Form
    {
        public TextBox m_txtEdit;

        public UserForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

//UserForm.Designer.cs
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    partial class UserForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.m_txtEdit = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.m_txtEdit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 100);
            this.m_txtEdit.Name = "m_txtEdit";
            this.m_txtEdit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(149, 20);
            this.m_txtEdit.Visible = true;
            this.Controls.Add(this.m_txtEdit);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean that you can focus the textbox clicking it, but not using Tab key?
If so, I would check the tab order of the textbox, maybe it's not what you are expecting.

Comment: Can you please share your code for more insights?

Comment: What i mean is - I can't select text by clicking and dragging the mouse. I can select the text by pressing SHIFT + Arrow though.

Comment: It is the kind of issue you'd see when the Capture property is set on the wrong control.  Perhaps because you used an usual event to display the 2nd window, don't use MouseDown.  You'll have to move over a bit, you are blocking the view on your screen.

Comment: @Hans Passant. I didn't get what you mean. My application is so simple that it has these 2 forms only (I just updated the source code in the original post). As you suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960185/adding-a-child-form-to-a-non-mdi-win-form-prevents-child-controls-inside-child-f) I set the border style for the child form to FormBorderStyle.None, then it started working. Strange.